# Rooted Android Access Denied (GPIO Access)

Tags: android, root, android-source

I am using android 17.1 Kongstakang for my raspberry pi 3 (it runs lineage OS). I enabled root for adb on the settings, and on my cmd, I ran `adb root` and `adb remount` (both succeeded).  I then connected to my device and ran `su`, and `whoami` returns `root`. I also see the beginning as a `#` instead of a `$`, so I know I am root. I `cd` into the folder, then tried to `cat export` and `nano export` the file in the `/sys/class/gpio`, all of which returns `cat: export: Permission denied` or  `[ Error reading export: Permission denied ]`. Any ideas why? For raspberry pi running kongstakang 17, do any of you have a good way of manipulatin the GPIO pins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to `ls -l` this. I had no permission as root. I just had to `chmod` and give myself access :)